# mysql concatenating extract results with string

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Current Code:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM timestamp_field) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM now())")
```

Instead of `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM now())`, I want `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())`, but I want to hard code the month in. How do I go about concatenating the extract results with the MM month, for example 09.

I tried a few options below, with no luck.

```
(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())09)

CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now()), 09) 

'EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())' + '09'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now()), '09');
```

The "`+`" operator is not for string concatenation, unless you use Microsoft SQL Server.

In MySQL, use `CONCAT()` or if you set SQL mode to `ANSI` or `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` you can use the standard "`||`" operator:

```
SET SQL_MODE := 'ANSI';
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now()) || '09';
```

Comment: Doh... indeed.. Sooo close. Thanks Bill